# "paint" like control within a web page

Tags: java, user-interface, controls

I am looking for a Java UI control which allows users to draw drawings which can internally stored as an image. I am looking for a very light weight control which does not slow down the page rendering.

Any pointer?

~Sri

Comment: try searching "oekaki" or "paint chat" in google.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at JavaFX. I'm not sure if there is a readily available component though.

Answer (score 0):

How would the loading of a java app affect the rendering of a page by the browser? Unless you're running on a single-core machine, they should have little effect on each other.